# Is there an "attack" on a user?

Tags: discussion

Reasonable questions seem to be asked by:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/229/ripper234

But I noticed negative votes on their questions...

Answer (score 4):

No, I think they just are asking low-quality questions. The only thing wrong here is that perhaps there should be more comments with constructive feedback.

Comment: +1 for more constructive feedback. i just edited one of his questions. let's see.

Answer (score 4):

**I close-voted one of his questions.**

So, this is my justification:

[This](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/408/23) question is just a blatantly off-topic and low quality question.

It doesn't have a definite answer. It is just too broad. However, if converted to a community wiki, it might be good to go. But, in the current state, it is plainly off-topic.

I see that he also asked a question about ETA's. Even that question cannot be answered specifically, not even by an internal team member. So, even that question is rightly closed.

However, it is to be seen as positive criticism and constructive feedback, and is for the greater good of this community!

Answer (score 3):

To be honest - I'm not familiar with Stackexchange and I am asking a lot of questions which may to be broad/duplicates or answering some with not enough details.  I feel the community is trying to help instead of attacking individuals.  There's a lot of figure out with Stack exchange.